# How to disable single finger dragging on touch devices

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

When a user is dragging the page on mobile browsers, it acts like scrolling but when it comes to the map and the users finger is on the map, leaflet's dragging event is fired and scrolling is not.

I want to disable single finger dragging but keep double fingers dragging so that the user can drag the map with 2 fingers whilst scrolling the page with 1 finger.

Question: Is there any ways to do the above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is.
Just set dragging option to false and use tap option to keep scrolling up or down.

```
var oMap = new L.Map('Map', {
       '...Other options...'
       dragging: false,
       tap: false
    });
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: But this disables it on all devices. Is there a way to just disable it on mobile browsers, as the OP seems to be asking?

Comment: @lucas get the screen size for mobile and desktop and toggle the dragging and tap variables accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but getting the screen size is not always trivial. I later found this helpful utility that is part of leaflet, `L.Browser.mobile`, allowing you to do something like `dragging: !L.Browser.mobile,`

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I found this solution under a leaflet Github issue as well.
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4544